# Convergence when the derivative is uniformly continuous

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Let $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be a derivable function. $f'$ is uniformly continuous in $\Bbb R$

> Prove that $[n(f(x+1/n)-f(x))]$ converges uniformly to $f'(x)$

I'm having a hard time seeing why does $f'$ being uniformly continuous help me and I tried to assume negatively that it doesn't converge uniformly but that didn't really get me anywhere.

Thanks

edit:  Can anyone think of a derivable function that its derivative isn't uniformly continuous and doesn't maintain:$[n(f(x+1/n)−f(x))]$ converges uniformly to $f'(x)$ ?

Comment: Use the mean value theorem and then the uniform continuity of the derivative.

Comment: Thank you Svetoslav! Can you (or anyone else) think of a derivable function that its derivative isn't uniformly continuous and doesn't maintain :$[n(f(x+1/n)−f(x))]$ converges uniformly to $f′(x)$

Comment: @lfc: the one I have seen is $f(x)=\frac{\sin(e^x)}{1+x^2}$. It is uniformly continuous with unbounded derivative. If we relax the requirement that $f$ be defined on $\mathbb R$ then  $f(x)=\sqrt x$ defined on $R^+$ will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference quotient is equal to $f'(\xi)$ for some $\xi\in(x,x+1/n)$. Now because of the uniform continuity of the derivative you have that for each $\epsilon >0\exists \delta >0$ that $|f'(x)-f'(y)|\leq \epsilon \forall x,y: |x-y|\leq \delta$. Chose $1/n\leq \delta$ and you have it.

Answer (score 1):

For each $n\in N$ there is a $c_{n}\in (x,x+\frac{1}{n})$ such that $$\tag1n(f(x+1/n)-f(x))=f'(c_{n})$$

Let $\epsilon>0$.

Since $f'$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R$ we may choose $\delta >0$ such that

$\vert x-y\vert <\delta \Rightarrow \vert f'(x)-f'(y)\vert <\epsilon$.

Now, choose $N\in \mathbb N$ so large that $n>N\Rightarrow \frac{1}{n}<\delta $. Then as soon as $n>N$ we have $$\tag2\vert f'(c_{n})-f'(x)\vert <\epsilon $$

Comparing $(1)$ and $(2)$ now gives the result.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here use the mean value theorem, but it is possible, and perhaps slightly more natural, to use a weaker result known as the mean value inequality (see e.g. Körner's A Companion to Analysis).

The mean value inequality tells us if $N\leq f'(y)\leq M$ for all $y$ in some open interval then $$N\leq \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\leq M$$ for all $a\neq b$ in that interval.

The uniform continuity of $f'$ means precisely that given $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that
$$f'(x)-\epsilon\leq f'(y)\leq f'(x)+\epsilon$$
for all $x$ and all $y\in(x-\delta,x+\delta)$.

Now, using the mean value inequality,

$$-\epsilon\leq\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h-f'(x)\leq\epsilon$$

for all x and all $h\in(-\delta,\delta)\setminus\{0\}$, which is what we wanted to show.